# How to send email to multiple applicant via server action Odoo 14

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I have an email template and I want to use server action to send emails to multiple applicants for job refusal and archive the applicant after sending the email in Odoo 14.
How can I link this server action to the email template and archive the applicant after sending the email?
Any kinda help will be greatly appreciated.
Here's my code.

```xml
**Email Template:**
<record id="email_template_custom" model="mail.template">
    <field name="name">Job refusal: Send by email</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="hr_recruitment_custom.model_hr_applicant"/>
        <field name="email_from">${object.user_id.email_formatted |safe}</field>
        <field name="email_to">${object.email_from}</field>
        <field name="subject">Applied Job: (Ref ${object.job_id.name})</field>
        <field name="body_html" type="html">
        <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
             <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px;">
                  Dear ${object.partner_name}
                   <br/>
                   <br/>
                   We appreciate your interest in ${object.company_id.name} and the time you’ve invested in applying for the ${object.job_id.name} opening.
    
                   <br/>
                   <br/>
                   We ended up moving forward with another candidate, but we’d like to thank you for talking to our team and giving us the opportunity to learn about your skills and accomplishments.
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    We will be advertising more positions in the coming months.
                    We hope you’ll keep us in mind and we encourage you to apply again.
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    We wish you good luck with your job search and professional future endeavors.
    
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    Best,
                    ${object.user_id.name}
                    </p>
              </div>enter code here
         </field>
</record>
```

```py
**python file:**   
 def action_send_refusal_by_email(self):
        ctx = {}
        email_list = self.partner_id.mapped('email')
        if email_list:
            ctx['email_to'] = ','.join([email for email in email_list if email])
            ctx['email_from'] = self.env.user.emoployee_id.email
            ctx['send_email'] = True
            ctx['partner_id'] = ''
            template = self.env.ref('hr_recruitment_custom.email_template_custom')
            template.with_context(ctx).send_mail(self.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=False)
```

```xml
**Server action:**    
<record id="action_refuse_applicants" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Milti refuse Applicants</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="hr_recruitment_custom.email_template_custom"/>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="hr_recruitment_custom.email_template_custom"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">records.action_send_refusal_by_email()</field></record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your server action and add replace record_model, with the actual model the record belongs to

```xml
**Server action:**    
<record id="action_refuse_applicants" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Multi refuse Applicants</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="hr_recruitment_custom.record_model"/>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="hr_recruitment_custom.record_model"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">records.action_send_refusal_by_email()</field></record>
```

On the python side, you first have to loop through self, to avoid singleton errors.

```py
def action_send_refusal_by_email(self):
    for rec in self:
        ctx = {}
        #email_list = self.partner_id.mapped('email')
        # if email_list:
        ctx['email_to'] = rec.partner_id.email
        ctx['email_from'] = self.env.user.employee_id.email
        ctx['send_email'] = True
        ctx['partner_id'] = rec.partner_id.id
        template = self.env.ref('hr_recruitment_custom.email_template_custom')
        template.with_context(ctx).send_mail(
            rec.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=False)
        rec.active = False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is sending emails now although not archiving the applicants selected. How can I archive the applicants after sending emails to them?

Comment: Ediited the answer by adding rec.active=False. Define active field if it does not exist

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eric, all is working well.